# Is it possible for a magical knight to increase his amount of mana in Black Clover?

Tags: black-clover

In Black Clover, some magic knights run out of mana quickly after a few spells and others can use a lot of spells because "they have a lot of mana". How does this people to have a lot of mana? Can they train to increase it? Is the mana you are born with the only mana you'll ever have?

To summarize the question, Is it possible for a magical knight to increase his amount of mana in Black Clover?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible for a magic knight to increase the amount of mana they have. Though a few very skilled magic knights can use a skill called mana zone which lets them use more mana than they have by taking mana from the environment. Their mana doesn't increase as they grow but the number of spells they have and the complexity and power of the spells does increase. They can also control their mana better which leads to greater power as shown by Yuno and his Spirit Dive.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer to the question as that is not something your average magic knight can use. What I think is being asked is if they can increase the amount of mana that they can hold not if they can find ways to get it from other sources temporarily

Comment: I answered that above. "It isn't possible for a magic knight to increase the amount of mana they have."

Comment: I am not sure if that is true, from what I have seen in the series they do seem to grow in power overall as they gain experience which one would assume also includes the amount of mana they have. Or are you assuming that the amount of mana that the captains have was the same as when they where first becoming knights. I would think it is more accurate to say we don’t know how they can increase their mana.

Comment: Their mana doesn't increase as they grow but the number of spells they have and the complexity and power of the spells does increase. They can also control their mana better which leads to greater power as shown by Yuno and his Spirit Dive.

Comment: this isn't true you can increase your mana when you grow older but the mana regen will slow down

Answer (score -1):

It is possible through magic stones

> Magic stones 「魔石 Maseki」 are eleven ancient magic jewels that can
> amplify magic power and can serve as multipliers for magic spells.

[Magic Stone](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_stone)